# How to get dynamic Summary or short description from Solr index

Tags: solr, index

I am constructing a listing page by querying Solr Index where I am getting

> [Title], [Summary], [Published Date], [Body] etc.,

The Solr index is returning all the indexed fields and so far so good. The problem for me is if [Summary] field is not populated by the content author, I have to get **some dynamic text** (like a couple of lines) from [Body] field, which is an RTE. Any thoughts/ ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create computed index field and write logic according to that if `Summary` field is empty in that case it will go to `Body` field. And logic will be like that into your computed index field class. It is not exact code it's only condition should be like below.

```
public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   {
      Item item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

      if (item == null)
           return null;

     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Fields["Summary"].Value)) {
        return item.Fields["Summary"].Value
       }
    else {
    return item.Fields["Body"].Value
    }
}
```

Then use this computed index field into your query and rebuild your indexes, I think it will start working.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

To populate some dynamic text when the `summary` field is not available so you can use the `computed field` for the `summary` field and in that `computed field` you can check if any value is coming or not and on that basis, you can add some dynamic text.

You can check more about the computed field here https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/create-a-computed-index-field.html

Comment: Thanks for writing. The dynamic text I required should be some random text like first two lines from [Body] field of that article. Each article has its own description and they are not same. Also, I can't define some static text to the computed field.

Comment: You do not need to write static text, you can write your own logic to get text